How to hide a class of a property from users of my type library
Is there any way to prevent my class library users to use some auxiliary class directly but to access another public class public property which is of that auxiliary type?
I mean
class AuxClass {...}
public class MainClass
{
    public AuxClass Prop { get; set; } = new AuxClass();
    ...
}

so that users of MainClass should be able to manipulate the Prop property of a variable of this class but should not be able to create variables of type AuxClass. Ideally not even to see it in IntelliSense suggestions.
For now on I only came up with idea to declare constructors of AuxClass as internal ones.
Is there some better way?

There's a difference between "not allowing instantiation of a type" and "not having access to the type in the first place". You've already figured out the answer to the former. I don't think you're really going to benefit from trying to do the latter.

What's the point of making Prop settable if the user can't create objects to assign to it?

How would consuming code be able to use Prop if it doesn't know what AuxClass is?  Why specifically are you trying to do this?  What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

@Mathias R. Jessen
The point is to design a class in such a way that a property of its type would never be accessable directly))) Instead particular objects should be accessed via indexer methods of that class wich fulfill LINQ queries... Take a look at my comment 4 David for detailes

@David
You are extremely perceptive!))) The problem I've mentioned is just a top of an iceberg... Frankly speaking, I'm trying to design an enrollment above OpenXMLFormat API to fulfill primitive tasks with Excel files in a more convinient manner.
My fantasy is to declare a property of a class that couldn't be manipulated by the consuming code as a "whole" property. Instead I'm dreaming to implement indexer methods that would return a particular cell by its referance (something like Cell["A1"]).

A common approach would be to expose an interface as the property and not your actual class, and of course initialize that property directly or from your public class constructor, making it a readonly property:
public interface IAnInterfaceForMyHiddenAuxClass // don't use this name
{
    // whatever public properties you want to expose here
}

internal class AuxClass : IAnInterfaceForMyHiddenAuxClass 
{
    // implementation here
}

public class MainClass
{
    public IAnInterfaceForMyHiddenAuxClass Prop { get; } = new AuxClass();
    ...
}


Yeahp... Thanks! I was thinking about this way
